# Integrating Squared of Interpolating Function with respect to one variable

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, calculus-and-analysis

I am interested in evaluating a two dimensional interpolating function produced by solving the wave equation. Here is the code that includes the resulting interpolating function.

```
pde = D[y[x, t], t, t] == D[y[x, t], x, x]

solnDerivative = NDSolve[{pde, y[x, 0] == Exp[-(x)^2], Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][y][-50, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][-50, t],
  Derivative[1, 0][y][50, t] == - Derivative[0, 1][y][50, t]}, 
  Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t], {x, -50, 50}, {t, 0, 130}]

ifunDerivative  = First[Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t] /. solnDerivative]
```

Here, I wanted to first integrate squared of `ifunDerivative` with respect to t from `{0,130}` then get a new interpolating function as a function of `x` only.

The first problem I ran into is that it won't evaluate this integral and spits back out the input.

```
integratedFunction = Integrate[(ifunDerivative[x, t])^2, {t, 0, 130}, x]
```

How can I go about numerically integrating interpolating function squared with respect to `t`? Then, obtain a solution that depends only on `x`? 
Please help me! Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure about the code `integratedFunction = Integrate[(ifunDerivative[x, t])^2, {t, 0, 130}, x]`.  Do you want *indefinite* integral with respect to `x` followed by the *definite* integral with respect to `t`?

Comment: Hello, I wanted to evaluate definite integral with respect to t from {t,0,130} and then express the resulting interpolating function in terms of x, then graph it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can integrate `Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2` along with the `pde`:

```
pde = D[y[x, t], t, t] == D[y[x, t], x, x];

solnDerivative = 
 NDSolve[{pde, y[x, 0] == Exp[-(x)^2], Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0,
     Derivative[1, 0][y][-50, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][-50, t], 
     Derivative[1, 0][y][50, t] == -Derivative[0, 1][y][50, t],
     (**)
     Derivative[0, 1][int][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2, 
     int[x, 0] == 0},
   {Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t], int[x, 130]}, {x, -50, 50}, {t, 0, 130}]
```

The integral may be obtained and a value for `x` substituted with

```
int[x, 130] /. First@solnDerivative /. x -> 10
```

Here is a plot (on the grid generated by `NDSolve`), which seems a little wobbly around `x == 0`:

```
ListLinePlot[{x, int[x, 130] /. First@solnDerivative} /. x -> # & /@ 
  Head[Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t] /. First@solnDerivative]["Grid"][[All, 1, 1]],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are some values of `int[x, 130]` compared with the result of integrating the derivative from the computed derivative `Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]`, with values of `x` taken among the grid computed by `NDSolve`:

```
Table[{
  int[x, 130] /. First[solnDerivative],
  (int[x, 130] /. First[solnDerivative]) - 
   NIntegrate[Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2 /. First[solnDerivative], 
    Evaluate@
     Prepend[Head[Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t] /. First@solnDerivative]["Grid"][[1, All, 2]], t]]},
 {x, Head[Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t] /. First@solnDerivative]["Grid"][[All, 1, 1]][[;; ;; 37]]}]
(*
  {{0.317956, -0.00806953},    {0.324704,  0.0000186443}, {0.326885,  2.02759*10^-6},
   {0.334907,  0.000021252},   {0.340367,  0.0000134228}, {0.342387,  0.00011331},
   {0.341913,  0.000136063},   {0.657123, -0.000169644},  {0.344552,  0.000135694},
   {0.348381,  0.000113308},   {0.356022,  0.0000133392}, {0.374857,  0.0000212584},
   {0.400694,  1.89176*10^-6}, {0.405668,  0.0000179112}, {0.423675, -0.00942803}}
*)
```

---

#### V8 Code

The code above does not run on V8.0.4.  The return expression `int[x, 130]` with the value `130` for `t`.  My preference is to return the `InterpolatingFunction` without the arguments.  Another issue is that the code complains about a spatial error estimate being too great (with a grid of 933 points).  Setting `"MinPoints"` to `1000` solves that problem.

```
solnDerivative = 
 NDSolve[{pde, y[x, 0] == Exp[-(x)^2], Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0,
    Derivative[1, 0][y][-50, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][-50, t], 
   Derivative[1, 0][y][50, t] == -Derivative[0, 1][y][50, t],
   (**)
   Derivative[0, 1][int][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2, int[x, 0] == 0},
  {Derivative[0, 1][y], int},
  {x, -50, 50}, {t, 0, 130},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 1000}}]
```

The rest of the code above may be used as is.  One might want to change the `37` to something like `100` in the `Table` example.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer. I have a question regarding your NDSolve. What exactly is happening at ""   (**) Derivative[0, 1][int][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2,  int[x, 0] == 0},{Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t], int[x, 130]}""

Comment: Why is  Derivative[0, 1][int][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2? And what is the purpose of this int[x,t] function? Thank you so much for your input. It is helping me alot!

Comment: @soccerboyz9341 You're welcome. The extra equations form an IVP that represents the `t` integral of the square of the derivative, `Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2`.  The expression `int[x, t]` represents the integral from `0` to `t`, so `int[x, 130]` is the integral you seek.  The second argument `{Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t], int[x, 130]}` tells `NDSolve` what functions (and in what form) to return.  The return value `solnDerivative` will consist of two rules, one for each function.

Comment: thank you again. Is there a reason why there is an additional condition int[x, 0] == 0?

Comment: @soccerboyz9341 In TeX, `Derivative[0, 1][int][x, t] == Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t]^2` is $\partial (\hbox{int(x,t)})/\partial t = (\partial y /\partial t)^2$ so that $\hbox{int}(x,t_0) = \int_0^{t_0} (\partial y /\partial t)^2\;dt$.  The condition `int[x, 0] == 0` is what defines the starting value of the integral -- it corresponds to $\int_0^{0} (\partial y /\partial t)^2\;dt = 0$.

Comment: Hello, I am getting the following error when I run your first two lines of code: "NDSolve::alliv: "The function int[x,130] was specified without dependence on all the independent variables. Each function must depend on all the independent variables" I am using Mathematica 8, is this the main problem? I think the error is due to int[x,130] and they expect int[x,t]?? Thank you

Comment: @soccerboyz9341 Yes, they keep expanding the functionality of   `NDSolve`.  There was another problem, which I addressed in an update of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't the most beatuiful thing, but it is what I'd do:

```
integratedFunction[xx_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(ifunDerivative /. {x -> xx, t -> tt})^2, {tt, 0, 130}]
```

Comment: Also, you should probably add //Quiet at the end.