# Reduce the dimension of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, finite-element-method, interpolation

So I have been trying to extract 2D interpolating function(x,t) or (y,t) from 3D interpolating function(x,y,t) by replacing y=0 or x=0. My domain is triangular(see below). Ultimately, I want to integrate this extracted function along the line(x=0) over the time. So far I am having trouble doing it. Here is the example code:

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
fksol  = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0, 0][u][x, y, t] + 
       Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][x, y, t] + 
       Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x, y, t] + 
       Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, y, t] == 
       Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, t] + NeumannValue[0, x + y >= 1], 
       u[x, y, 0] == (Erf[x/.1] - Erf[(x - 1)/.1] - 1) (Erf[y/.1] - 
       Erf[(y - 1)/.1] - 1) (PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, .1], x]*
       PDF[NormalDistribution[.8, .1], y] // Evaluate), 
       u[0, y, t] == 0, u[x, 0, t] == 0}, u, {x, y} ∈ region, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Why doesn't the `fksol[0,y,t]` give me  interpolating function with only two variables domain?

I tried to workaround similar to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110377/extract-one-dimension-from-an-n-dimensional-interpolatingfunction?rq=1), but kernel crashes for     `fksol["ValuesOnGrid"]`.

Thanks.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101678)

Comment: [Here's another related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128731/plot-1d-slice-of-2d-interpolatingfunction).  Unfortunately it uses `if["Grid"]`, which also causes the kernel to crash on your example.

Comment: @J.M.  [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59573/integrating-squared-of-interpolating-function-with-respect-to-one-variable) also uses the NDSolve, I have tried to do the same, but haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want the function along x=0 and y= 0 for all time  t. So it's spatial slice rather than time slice.

Comment: There's no natural way, because the spatial region is triangulated.  Reinterpolation is probably the easiest way to go (i.e. use `Interpolate` and `Table`).  There is also `fksolX0[y_, t_] := fksol[0, y, t]` if you just want a 2-variable function.

Comment: @MichaelE2 For reinterpolation I need the values on grid, right? But kernel crashes when i try to do `fksol["Grid"]`. Simply redefining the function with value doesn't work when taking integration like 
`NIntegrate[fksolX0[y, t], {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1} ]` . I know function is zero at either `x = 0` or `y = 0`, but the integration of derivative of `fksol` shouldn't be zero. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking something like `Table[{{y, t}, fksol[y, t]}, {y, 0., 1., 0.01}, {t, 0., 1., 0.01}]` and not `"Grid"`.  -- I'm confused about the `NIntegrate`: The code in your comment has no derivatives but you say "integration of derivative...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Too long for a comment, and possibly an answer....*

Question/comment, based on the OP and comments:

The following integrates `fksol[0.1, y, t]` over the slice of the interpolating function's domain where `x == 0.1`.  Is that what you're after?

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

emesh = fksol["ElementMesh"];

getY[x0_] := 
 With[{emx = ToElementMesh@ DiscretizeRegion@
      RegionIntersection[MeshRegion@emesh, ImplicitRegion[x >= x0, {x, y}]]},
  With[{coords = emx["Coordinates"]},
   With[{bdy = emx["BoundaryElements"] /. LineElement -> List /. 
       idcs : {__Integer} :> coords[[idcs]]},
    Union @@ 
     Cases[bdy, seg : {{x_ /; x == x0, _} ..} :> seg[[All, 2]], Infinity]
    ]]];

tpts = Last@fksol["Coordinates"];

int[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := fksol[x, y, t];
With[{x = 0.1},
 NIntegrate[int[x, y, t],
  Evaluate@{y, Sequence @@ getY[x]},
  Evaluate@{t, Sequence @@ tpts}, AccuracyGoal -> 17]
 ]
(*  0.039357  *)
```

Comment: Yes, ultimately I want to integrate the function  `fksol[0.1, y, t]` .  I think you missed to define `tpts` in here.  I mean integration of derivative like: `With[{x = 0.1}, NIntegrate[Derivative[1,0,0][int][x, y, t],
  Evaluate@{y, Sequence @@ getY[x]},
  Evaluate@{t, Sequence @@ tpts}, AccuracyGoal -> 17]
 ]` . Thanks.

Comment: @sdc `tpts` has been added -- thanks!

Comment: I am adding this code which can get x-points for specified `y0`value.
                                                                                                            
 `getX[y0_] :=  With[{emy =  ToElementMesh@DiscretizeRegion@
RegionIntersection[MeshRegion@emesh, ImplicitRegion[y >= y0, {x, y}]]},
 With[{coordy = emy["Coordinates"]}, With[{bdx =   emy["BoundaryElements"] /. LineElement -> List /. idx : {__Integer} :> coordy[[idx]]}, Union @@ Cases[bdx, segx : {{_, y_ /; y == y0} ..} :> segx[[All, 1]], Infinity]]]]`

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the (reported) crash you can swap the order of t and the spatial variables like so:

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
fksol = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
      Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y] + 
      Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
      Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, y] == 
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], 
    u[0, x, y] == (Erf[x/.1] - Erf[(x - 1)/.1] - 1) (Erf[y/.1] - 
        Erf[(y - 1)/.1] - 
        1) (PDF[NormalDistribution[.2, .1], x]*
         PDF[NormalDistribution[.8, .1], y] // Evaluate), 
    u[t, 0, y] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] region];
fksol["ValuesOnGrid"]
```

Comment: This is good to know. Thanks. :)